# plsql: How to use an array variable in cursor

Tags: arrays, plsql, cursor

The following code is a sub-part of a bigger code where the array `modify_column_list` is declared and includes the column names of the table `beset_e_szerepmatrix`.

```
  declare
    cursor v_cur is select * from delta_stage.beset_e_szerepmatrix;
           v_rec delta_stage.beset_e_szerepmatrix%rowtype;
  
  begin
    open v_cur;
    
    loop
      fetch v_cur into v_rec;
      exit when v_cur%notfound;
      
      v_sql := null;
      for i in 1..modify_column_list.count loop
        if v_sql is null and v_rec.modify_column_list(i) = 0 then
          v_sql := modify_column_list(i);
        else
          if v_sql is not null and v_rec.modify_column_list(i) = 0 then
            v_sql := v_sql || ', ' || v_rec.modify_column_list(i);
          end if;
        end if;
      end loop;
      v_rec.adathianyos_mezo := v_sql;
    end loop;
    close v_rec;
  end;
```

Every columns include 0 or 1 value in the table `beset_e_szerepmatrix`. In the column `adathianyos_mezo` should include all column names, where the record has 0 value. How can I use the modify_column_list(i) in the cursor?

Comment: what is `adathianyos_mezo` and its datatype ? beside your question , when loop through v_cur what will happen if a column has value `0` in first record but in the second record has value `1` ? does output of `select * from delta_stage.beset_e_szerepmatrix` is only one record then ?

Comment: The 'adathianyos_mezo' is varchar(4000). If a column has value '0' then its column name should be put into 'adatianyos_mezo' (if there is an other column which has value '0' then its column name should be concatenated to the previous '0' value column name in the 'adathianyos_mezo'). If the value '1' then do nothing. This examination is necessery for every records of 'delta_stage.beset_e_szerepmatrix'.

Comment: I understood like if lets say `col1=0`,`col2=1` and `col3=0` then `adathianyos_mezo = 'col1,col3'` But what if there are two records in `'delta_stage.beset_e_szerepmatrix'` for first record(row 1) `col1=0` but for second(row2) `col1=1` should it be removed from adathianyos_mezo so final value will be `adathianyos_mezo = 'col3'` ?